# Run Excel Macro using SSIS throught SQL Jobs failed

Tags: excel, ssis, sql-job, vba

I have a task to create Excel VBA and run that macro on SSIS. I can successfully run the Excel Macro from the SSIS Package, but I have a problem when I run that SSIS on SQL Jobs. I have created Credential, Proxy SSIS, and set SSIS unprotected, but it always fails.

**Error Message**

> Executed as user: HARNANDA7-PC\HARNANDA7.
>
> Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
>
> Version 11.0.2100.60 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Started:  11:56:14
>
> Error: 2014-05-28 11:56:17.61     Code: 0x00000001
>
> Source: Script
>   Task
>
> Description: Exception has been thrown by the target of an
>   invocation.  End Error
>
> DTExec: The package execution returned
>   DTSER_FAILURE (1).
>
> Started:  11:56:14  Finished: 11:56:17  Elapsed: 
>   2.652 seconds.
>
> The package execution failed.  The step failed.

but if i create Folder named "Desktop" on `C:/Windows/System32/config/systemprofile/` or `C:/Windows/SysWOW64/config/systemprofile/`
then the SSIS package runs successfully through SQL Jobs.

I'm confused as to what the problem is here. Can anyone help?

Big thanks

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason (no one seems to know from what I can gather), Excel requires that the desktop folder be present on your machine. It must use it as a global setting or possibly a default setting for creating files or temporary files. If that folder doesn't exists then (and this is just a guess) excel either has issues creating these temporary files or requires that the Desktop directory exists and, in both cases, throws an error if the Desktop directory does not exist.

I doubt that they would want to make something like this an explicit feature, so it is most likely a bug with Excel.